# MVC Routing - Use route part to switch views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a series of URLs that look like

```
/Catalog/Ajax/Update/{ViewToUpdate}?var1=a&var2=b&var3=c
```

Currently I've setup several routes - one for each {ViewToUpdate} and what I'd like to do is pass the {ViewToUpdate} to my Action handler so I can condense my code.  Instead of:

```
public ActionResult AjaxUpdateNavigation(string var1, string var2, string var3) {}
```

I'd like:

```
public ActionResult AjaxUpdateNavigation(string ViewToUpdate, string var1, string var2, string var3) {}
```

Here are my current routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
"CatalogAjaxNavigation",
"Catalog/Ajax/Update/Navigation",
new { controller = "Catalog", action = "AjaxUpdateNavigation" }
);
```

How do I set up the route definition correctly to handle both the {ViewToUpdate} string as well as still pass in the querystring?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my route:

```
  routes.MapRoute("TestThing", "test/{ViewToUpdate}", new {controller = "Home", action = "TestQSParams"});
```

Here's my action:

```
  public ActionResult TestQSParams(string ViewToUpdate, string var1, string var2)
  {
      TestQSParamsModel m = new TestQSParamsModel {var1 = var1, var2 = var2, ViewToUpdate = ViewToUpdate};
      return View("TestQSParams", m);
  }
```

Here's my model:

```
public class TestQSParamsModel
  {
      public string ViewToUpdate { get; set; }
      public string var1 { get; set; }
      public string var2 { get; set; }
  }
```

Here's my view:

```
From QS:<br />
  <% foreach(string s in Request.QueryString) 
         Response.Write(string.Format("{0}={1}<br />", s, Request.QueryString[s])); %>
  <br />
  <br />
  From Model:<br />
  <asp:Literal ID="modelvars" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

The view codebehind:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      modelvars.Text = string.Format("{0}<br />{1}<br />{2}", Model.var1, Model.var2, Model.ViewToUpdate);
  }
```

My url:

```
/test/ThisView?var0=douglas&var1=patrick&var2=caldwell
```

Finally, my result:

```
  From QS:   
  var0=douglas   
  var1=patrick   
  var2=caldwell

  From Model:
  patrick
  caldwell
  ThisView
```

Comment: One question. Why is the Webform Page Event there? IE. Page_Load.

Comment: From the olden days before MVC.Net got rid of them would be my guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
routes.MapRoute(
"CatalogAjaxNavigation",
"Catalog/Ajax/Update/{ViewToUpdate}",
new { controller = "Catalog", action = "AjaxUpdateNavigation" , ViewToUpdate = (string)null }
);


public ActionResult AjaxUpdateNavigation(string ViewToUpdate, string var1, string var2, string var3) {}
```